# .htaccess Joomla in the root and CodeIgniter not redirecting correctly

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, joomla, subdirectory

I have a Joomla site in the root folder, with the default .htaccess, and I can't reach the CodeIgniter app located in the subfolder *TEST*; I can see only the preset welcome page of the CodeIgniter app, and I can tell that the `$config['base_url']` is set properly.

When I try to get a controller, I get the 404 sef error of Joomla.

I guess it's a problem about .htaccess. Can someone help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change htaccess Joomla to work with CI in subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860465/change-htaccess-joomla-to-work-with-ci-in-subfolder)

Comment: That's very similar, but i tried to put the suggested .htaccess but it show error 404 now.